# Drush cannot rr or en a module

Tags: drush, composer

I have a Drupal 7 dev-site hosted on pantheon. Using git bash and composer I installed drush on my windows 10 machine and I thought I did so globally. When I run composer --version and drush status I get what appear to be good responses. However, when I try to enable a module using drush or rebuild the registry I get ...

```
samha@LAPTOP-99SBTCQM /c/localworking/thecottagepress (master *=) $ drush 
@pantheon.thecottagepress.dev rr
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Here is what I get when I run drush status...

```
samha@LAPTOP-99SBTCQM /c/localworking/thecottagepress (master *=) $ drush 
status Drupal version         :  7.56
Site URI               :  http://default
PHP configuration      :  C:\PHP\php.ini
PHP OS                 :  WINNT
Drush script           :  
C:/LocalWorking/thecottagepress/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php
Drush version          :  8.1.15
Drush temp directory   :  C:\Users\samha\AppData\Local\Temp
Drush configuration    :
Drush alias files      :  C:/Users/samha/.drush/pantheon.aliases.drushrc.php
Drupal root            :  C:\LocalWorking\thecottagepress
Drupal Settings File   :  sites/default/settings.php
Site path              :  sites/default
```

What do I need to do to make drush fully functional? I have researched for most of today whith no luck. Thank you. Sam

Answer (score 0):

If you are running drush on you're local site, you do not need to include `@pantheon.thecottagepress.dev` to run the command. Just run drush from your site root as so: `drush rr`. Drush won't be able to run the command on a remote machine if it can't resolve the domain name.

Comment: Blake, when I run drush rr I get..."The drush command 'rr' could not be found. Run 'drush cache-clear drush' to clear the commandfile cache if you have installed new extensions. [error]. Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database. [error]". When I run "drush cc drush" it succeeds. Then if I run drush rr again I get the same error as above. When I run drush @pantheon... rr I get the /bin/bash/ error again as stated in my original post. Thoughts?